# Big Batch of Entity Framework Updates Much Slower Than Batching Myself

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Updating a bunch of records is much slower using what I think are standard entity framework techniques than batching the same queries it would generate myself.  For 250 records I see entity framework about 10 times as slow.  For 1000 records it goes up to about 20 times slower.

When I log the database activity for entity framework, I see it is generating the same basic queries I would generate myself, but it seems to be running them one at a time instead of all at once, even though I only call SaveChanges once.  Is there any way to ask it to run the queries all at once?

I can't do a simple mass SQL update because in my real use case each row needs to be processed separately to determine what to set the fields to.

Sample timing code is below:

```
var stopwatchEntity = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
var stopwatchUpdate = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
using (var dbo = new ProjDb.dbo("Server=server;Database=database;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
    var resourceIds = dbo.Resources.Select(r => r.ResourceId).Take(250).ToList();

    //dbo.Database.Log += (s) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

    stopwatchEntity.Start();
    foreach (var resourceId in resourceIds)
    {
        var resource = new ProjDb.Models.dbo.Resource { ResourceId = resourceId };
        dbo.Resources.Attach(resource);
        resource.IsBlank = false;
    }
    dbo.SaveChanges();
    stopwatchEntity.Stop();

    stopwatchUpdate.Start();
    var updateStr = "";
    foreach (var resourceId in resourceIds)
        updateStr += "UPDATE Resources SET IsBlank = 0 WHERE ResourceId = " + resourceId + ";";
    dbo.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(updateStr);
    stopwatchUpdate.Stop();

    MessageBox.Show(stopwatchEntity.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("f") + ", " + stopwatchUpdate.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("f"));
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: What slow things down is the interface between Net and the database.  Using linq methods are faster.  The ExecuteSqlCommand is the slow method.  You should be able to use linq on the "resource" object to get same results.

Comment: It seems like EF can't batch updates. Can you try EF Core? One of the new features is the ability to do batch updates.

Comment: @jdweng if you have an example of how linq methods could be faster given anything like the use case I have above, please post as an answer and I'd be love to try it out.

Comment: @kirchner in the short term I cannot use EF Core.  I do see that that feature has been added to EF Core, so I will keep it in mind for the future.  Thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @EricEJ and @Kirchner reported, EF6 doesn't support batch update. However, some third-party libraries do.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Batch Update allows updating multiples rows with the same value/formula.

For example:

```
context.Resources
    .Where(x => resourceIds.Contains(x => x.ResourceId)
    .Update(x => new Resource() { IsBlank = false });
```

Since entities are not loaded in the context, you should get the best performance available.

Read more: http://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

If the value must differ from a row to another, this library allows `BulkUpdate` features. This library is a paid library but pretty much supports everything you need for performance:

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

For example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);
context.BulkMerge(customers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 6 does not support batching, EF Core does